# How to implement multi dispatching with c++ function template

Tags: templates, c++17, overloading

Here is what I want:

```
struct type1{};

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_xxx_v<T, type1>,void>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T& obj)
{
    std::cout << "operation on type1" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_xxx_v<T, type1>,void>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T& obj)
{
    std::cout << "operation on other types" << std::endl;
}
```

after days, i have to add another type
`struct type2{};`

But how can I implement `my_function` for `type1`, `type2` and other types?
I can write it like this:

```
struct type2{};

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_xxx_v<T, type1>,void>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T& obj)
{
    std::cout << "operation on type1" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_xxx_v<T, type2>,void>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T& obj)
{
    std::cout << "operation on type2" << std::endl;
}

// my_function for other types
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_xxx_v<T, type1> && !std::is_xxx_v<T, type2>,void>* = nullptr>
void my_function(const T& obj)
{
    std::cout << "operation on other types" << std::endl;
}
```

but this is not a good method, since one day, i add `struct type3{};`, i have to add a new func for `type3` (i can accept this), but i also have to change code for other types which i don't want to.

what i want is if i add a new `type3`, is that possible that i only add a new overloaded function for `type3`, and the code for other types has no need to change.

Comment: are you able to use c++20? or only c++17?

Comment: c++17 only, and currently i use class template and partial specialization to implement this, but i want to learn how to fix this by function template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the `std::is_xxx_v` you use, you might be able to use [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). First declare the default function working with any type of argument:

```
template<typename T>
void my_function_specialization(const T& obj) {
    std::cout << "operation on other types" << std::endl;
}
```

And then you can specialize the function on the types you want

```
template<>
void my_function_specialization(const type1& obj) {
    std::cout << "operation on type1" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void my_function_specialization(const type2& obj) {
    std::cout << "operation on type2" << std::endl;
}
/*
 and so on...
*/
```

Otherwise you can use `if constexpr` to distingush between different cases:

```
template<typename T>
void my_function_if_constexpr(const T& obj) {
    if constexpr (std::is_xxx_v<type1, T>) {
        std::cout << "operation on type1" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (std::is_xxx_v<type2, T>) {
        std::cout << "operation on type2" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr (/* and so on... */) {
        /* ... */
    } else {
        std::cout << "operation on other types" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[See Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YanjTqxxK)

Comment: thanks very much for your reply, i am not prefer the specialization(for every single type) version, since there might many types, and some type has common attribute with type1, some type has common attribute with type2, and so on... ,so i use std::is_xxx_v<type1,T>. The second version can fix this,  now i am try to use tag dispatching to implement this, and create a tag for type1(type1.1/type1.2/...), another tag for type2(type2.1/type2.2...). thanks again for your advice.